# Zoom out camera while keeping text locked - Phaser 3

Tags: javascript, camera, zooming, game-development, phaser-framework

I'm making a sword game in which you have to collect coins to get big and you fight people. Here's what I have so far:
[image: Player gets bigger as he collects coins]

Notice how the player gets bigger as it collects coins. After a while, you get so big that you cover the entire screen.

[image: big player]

I realized I have to zoom out the camera based on the players size.

This is what I have for camera (in create function)

`this.cameras.main.startFollow(this.mePlayer);`

I added this line of code before it:
`this.cameras.main.setZoom(0.5)`

Now it turns like this. The text is all smaller and for some reason my tileSprite background breaks too.

[image]

Here is the code for the text.

```
        //killcounter
        this.killCount = this.add.text(window.innerWidth / 1.5, 0, 'Kills: 0', {
            fontFamily: 'Georgia, "Goudy Bookletter 1911", Times, serif'
        }).setFontSize(40).setDepth(101);
        this.killCount.scrollFactorX = 0
        this.killCount.scrollFactorY = 0

        //player+fpscounter
        this.playerCount = this.add.text(this.cameras.main.worldView.x*this.cameras.main.zoom, this.cameras.main.worldView.y*this.cameras.main.zoom, 'Players: 0' + "\nFPS: 0", {
            fontFamily: 'Georgia, "Goudy Bookletter 1911", Times, serif'
        }).setFontSize(20).setDepth(101);
        this.playerCount.scrollFactorX = 0
        this.playerCount.scrollFactorY = 0
```

this is the code for my camera

```
this.cameras.main.startFollow(this.mePlayer);
```

...and this is the code for my background

```
//in create function
        this.background = this.add.tileSprite(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, 'background').setOrigin(0).setScrollFactor(0, 0);
        this.background.fixedToCamera = true;

//in update function
 this.background.setTilePosition(this.cameras.main.scrollX, this.cameras.main.scrollY);
```

Is there a way I can keep the text locked so that when the camera zooms out, it stays at the same position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to samme for helping me solve this.

In the end I created another camera called UICamera.

I used the `ignore` function to ignore all of the game objects on that camera.

And I ignored all the text, minimap, ui, and tilesprite background  on the main camera.

Then, to zoom out, I would just zoom out the main camera and adjust the tileSprite scale manually.

See http://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/camera/ignore